# JScrollPane is changing it's size

Tags: java, swing

I so my problem is this:

I made a JPanel. Inside it I want to add a JList with a scroll-bar. So I use JScrollPane.

Here you can see a picture of the application. The big white recangle is the size of the JPanel. In the second picture you see what happens when I add the Scrollpane to the code.

[image: Size of the JPanel]

[image: Size of the JList with JScrollPane.]

Here is the code I use:

```
public class GUI extends JFrame{

    DefaultListModel m = new DefaultListModel();
    JList myList = new JList(m);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(myList);
    JPanel listPanel = new JPanel();

    public GUI(){
    //Stuff about Frame Size, title, and other boring things

    scrollPane.setViewportView(myList);
    listPanel.add(scrollPane);
    this.add(listPanel);
    }
}
```

I have used it before, and it worked. Well, I faced the same problem, but it went away. I have written this code the same way as I did the previous time. But this time it doesn't work.

thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 1):

With `JList` you can simply use `setVisibleRowCount` to adjust the size of the viewable area of the `JScrollPane`

The other problem is `JPanel` uses a `FlowLayout` by default, you may want to change the use something like `BorderLayout` instead

**Updated**

As pointed out, if the list contains a large number of elements, you can use `setPrototypeValue` to improve the efficiency

Comment: setVisibleRowCount & setPrototypeValue

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so apparently I have to setPreferredSize. You can't just set the size of the panel, you need to set the size of the jscrolpane too!

Comment: No. With `JList` you can simply use `setVisibleRowCount` to adjust the size of the viewable area of the `JScrollPane`

Answer (score 0):

By default, unless you use something like a grid bag layout...

Also, for developing UI's in Java, it is extremely helpful to install an eclipse plugin called WindowBuilder

Comment: *"helpful to install an eclipse plugin called WindowBuilder"* which has a habit of using `null` layouts instead!  Not a good choice - IMHO

Comment: Umm only if you don't configure it? It is an extremely helpful tool... And the null layout by default is a exact layout. Not a null layout, simply the parameter passed to get this layout is null, as in default

Comment: Absolute Layout == Exact Layout == `null` layout, call it what you want, it's still a `null` layout, which is highly unrecommended. You wouldn't put a chainsaw in the hands of someone who's never cut wood. Without a firm understanding of how basic layout and container management, GUI editors tend to produce more problems than they solve, and yes, I use a form editor, but I also spent 10 years hand coding my GUIs. Knowing when to use a tool is as important as knowing which tool to use ;)